# How to subtract value from generic data

Tags: java, generics

I've defined a Point class like this.

```
class Point<E,F> {E x; E y; ...}
```

so that i can give float, Integer ... [anyway its a number]

But when i want to manipulate its an error.

```
void getdistance(Point<Number, Number> pt) {
    this.x-pt.x.floatValue();   //not a statement
    this.y-pt.y.floatValue();
}
```

also i should not give string as type, so should i change it to Number?
or any other way to calculate distance from generic type?

But if i change the type to Number how can i specify different co-ordinate type [float or integer]?

how to infer type here?

```
this.y-pt.y.TypeValue?
```

how can we do if its integer or double?

when i pass

```
pt.getdistance(otherpt);
```

compiler shows error: create a method getdistance(Float,Integer). how to pass other point to that method?

Answer (score 3):

Try and define your point like this: `Point<E extends Number, F extends Number>`.
That way the compiler can tell that `E` and `F` both are numbers.

However, you might even want to simplify that to `Point<N extends Number>` since most likely both coordinates should be of the same type (i.e. `Double`, `Integer` etc.) - mixing types seems quite odd to me.

The method would then have to be adjusted:

```
<X extends Number, Y extends Number> float getdistance(Point<X, Y> pt) {
  float dx = this.x.floatValue() - pt.x.floatValue();
  float dy = this.y.floatValue() - pt.y.floatValue();

  return (whatever your distance calculation needs to look like);
}
```

Note that x and y might be null, thus you'd have to check for that.
Specifying `X` and `Y` here would allow you to pass a `Point<Float, Integer>` to a `Point<Double, Long>`'s member method. You could redefine `E` and `F` here, but that might be a source of confusion.

**Edit**:

I'll elaborate a bit on Mark Peters' comment:

Using `floatValue()` or even `doubleValue()` might result in a loss of precision, since even `double` would not be able to accurately represent each `long` value. Thus you might experience severe precision losses, especially with higher numbers.

Additionally, `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` are numbers too and those have even higher precision.

In order to get maximum precision, you'd have to use `BigDecimal` in the calculation and when creating the initial values you'd have to check the types of the values and call the appropriate method:

- for `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer` and `Long` you'd call `BigDecimal.valueof( x.longValue() )`
- for `Float` and `Double` you'd call `BigDecimal.valueof( x.doubleValue() )`
- `BigDecimal` could be used as is
- `BigInteger` would be passed to the `BigDecimal` constructor

This would add quite a bit of complexity and in that case you might want to go with arshajii's suggestion of subclassing `Point` instead.

Comment: Both coordinates are declared with type `E` (I'm not sure where `F` comes in).

Comment: Well, since his example method parameter is `Point<Number, Number>`, I guess `E` and `F` mean the type of x and y.

Comment: i want it to be different, maybe<Float,Integer>

Comment: @Dineshkumar then use the first form. However, it still seems odd to me ;)

Comment: You need to be careful with this.  Since there is no data type that covers all of the other data types in full precision, using this in the general case could lose information.  For example, mixing `Float` and `Integer`.  `Integer` has a much greater precision for integer values than `Float` allows.  Calling `floatValue()` will lose that precision.

Comment: @MarkPeters you're right, mixing types and generifying the calculation has some limitations on the precision. One could try and use `BigDecimal` inside the method for more precision (especially with the calculation), but you'd still have to check the types for maximum precision.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the types that they should extend Number with:

```
<T extends Number, T1 extends Number>
```

This way you'll be able to pass it Float etc